# str.translate not removing characters (numerics and spaces) from filename

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I am executing the following code using python 3.7 to rename a number of files, removing any numerics or spaces in the file name. However, when retrieving the file list, none of the files are renamed. Any reason why?

Results are below the code.

```
import os

def rename_files():
    # get files names
    curr_dir = os.getcwd()
    print("Current WD: ",curr_dir)
    os.chdir(r"c:\udacity_files\prank")
    new_dir = os.getcwd()
    print("New WD: ",new_dir)
    file_list = os.listdir()
    for file_name in file_list:
        os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate("0123456789 "))
    new_list = os.listdir()
    print("New List: ", new_list)
    os.chdir(curr_dir)
    print("Restored WD: ",curr_dir)

rename_files()
```

Output:

```
Current WD:  C:\Users\qtbxxxx
New WD:  c:\udacity_files\prank
3New List:  ['16los angeles.jpg', '17cairo.jpg', '22rochester.jpg', '25madrid.jpg', '28houston.jpg', '29bristol.jpg', '29buenos aires.jpg', '2chennai.jpg', '2hyderabad.jpg', '35miami.jpg', '36sydney.jpg']
Restored WD:  C:\Users\qtbxxxx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a translate map with [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) in Python 3 for `translate` to work. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) for more info. Here's something you can try:

```
os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(str.maketrans('', '', '0123456789 ')))
```

The first two arguments for `str.maketrans` are irrelevant for your use so just leave them as empty strings. The third argument defines characters to be removed.