# Creating dummies from Column nested list

Tags: python, pandas, list

df3['col_two'] has nested lists of movie genres. I am trying to get dummies for each row regarding those genres. The problem I think I am having is that str.get_dummies() works but of course it reads for instance 'Adventure' and 'Adventure'] as two different things, but what I want is obviously having a column for each genre (i.e. one column for Adventure).

I have tried pd.series.replace() like this:

```
df3['col_two'].replace({'[':''})
```

or np.array like this

```
df3['col_two'] = np.array(df3['col_two'])
```

but they both give the same error:

```
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas
```

```
df['genres'] = df['genres'].str.split(pat='|')
df3 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['id'], value_vars=['genres'], var_name='col_one', 
value_name='col_two')
df3.head()

id  col_one col_two
0   135397  genres  [Action, Adventure, Science Fiction, Thriller]
1   76341   genres  [Action, Adventure, Science Fiction, Thriller]
2   262500  genres  [Adventure, Science Fiction, Thriller]
3   140607  genres  [Action, Adventure, Science Fiction, Fantasy]
4   168259  genres  [Action, Crime, Thriller]


df4 = df3["col_two"].str.get_dummies(",")
df4.head()


'Action'    'Action']   'Adventure' 'Adventure']    'Animation' 'Animation']    'Comedy'    'Comedy']   'Crime' 'Crime']    ... ['Romance'] ['Science Fiction'  ['Science Fiction'] ['TV Movie' ['Thriller' ['Thriller']    ['War'  ['War'] ['Western'  ['Western']
0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

what I'd like to make is having a column per genre without weird repetition due to unwanted extra characters like "]" etc etc. And the usual 0 or 1 dummy variables along the column.

Apologies for the weird layout of the last df and thank you in advance for every answer.

Answer (score 0):

A simple **.join** of the dummified column should work well. Try this:

```
df = df[['id', 'col_one']].join(df['col_two'].str.join('|').str.get_dummies().add_prefix('GENRE_'))
```

Let me know if this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

You can remove characters using `str.translate` and `str.maketrans` then use `get_dummies`:

```
no_bracket = df['col_two'].str.translate(str.maketrans('', '', '[]'))
no_bracket.str.get_dummies(',')
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55032310/6942527) and the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) for `str.translate` should provide a little more info on the parameters.